# Two load cells on a ADS1115 gives the same measurements

Tags: analog-to-digital

I have a raspberry Pi 3B+ board connected to an ADS1115 analog-to-digital converter. 2 load cells are attched to the same ADS1115(pins 0-1 and 2-3). I can individually calibrate/read weights from both load cells (scale 1 & 2) using Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15 python library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15). But, when I try to read two scales simultaneously, both scales display the weight in scale 2. I can neither calibrate nor read weight from scale 1. I tried SINGLE mode and CONTIONOUS mode. I got measurements after a delay, still no luck.

Any ideas, what may cause the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: No.  Photos, software listing, software outputs?

Comment: Hi @Ozcan KOC, Welcome and nice to meet you. (1) Ah, let me see. What do you mean by reading two (load cell) scales (channels) "simultaneously"? Unless you are using python mult-threading/multi-processing, you should only read two channels "sequentially". (2) Now suppose you read two channels sequentially, one after another, in single shot mode. One possibility is the following: after first shot, POWER is down automatically (See Section 3 of datasheet) . / to continue, ...

Comment: The problem is that even when power down, it is only the background analog to digital conversion guy goes to sleep, but the front desk guy still entertains your read request, only GIVING YOU THE OLD READING! :) Ref: (1) ADS1115 16bit ADC - TI
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf

(2) AliExpress I2C ADS1115 Module 
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32590193920.html

Comment: Another possibility is that you try to read another channel before the first channel has finished its conversion.  To avoid overrun, You can monitor the Conversion Ready Pin (Datasheet Section 9.3.8) and only read again when the Ready pin says OK.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am developing a GuiZero python mult-threading/multi-processing application. It seems that "read another channel before the first channel has finished its conversion" is possibly more relevant. However, I thought the Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15 library was handling the conversion delay, is it not the case?. Do I need to add delay (apparently more than 8ms according to data-sheet)?